# How do I use the non-greedy modifier when searching backwards?

Tags: ruby, regex, non-greedy

I have some queries like:

```
"$Prefex" SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name WHERE pal pal pal LIMIT "$Suffix"
```

These queries have unwanted prefixes and suffixes. I used a regex to get rid of the prefix using a non-greedy `.*?SELECT`.

I couldn't find a way to use the non-greedy modifier searching backward to eliminate the suffixes.

Ideally, I want a pattern to eliminate from the end of the line to the first match of "LIMIT".
If I use `LIMIT.*?` it wan't match anything, while if I use just `LIMIT.*` it was greedy, which I want to avoid.

I'm using Ruby for my language.

This is example of the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT $val1 $val2 WHERE {  $val1 a foaf:val1.$val1 foaf:val2 $val2. FILTER regex($val2 , "CITY LIMITED" , "i")} LIMIT 20&output=xml HTTP/1.1" 200 604 "-" "Python-urllib/2.6" "GB" "65465666654626426246524"
```

And this is the desired output:

```
SELECT DISTINCT $val1 $val2 WHERE {  $val1 a foaf:val1.$val1 foaf:val2 $val2. FILTER regex($val2 , "CITY LIMITED" , "i")}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of input and desired output?

Comment: FYI - rubular.com is a handy tool for regex

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is like:

```
"$Prefex" SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name WHERE pal pal pal LIMIT "$Suffix"
```

Then this regex will return your query with any text following the LIMIT, up to and not including the first `"`:

```
/(SELECT.*?LIMIT.*?\}).*?/
```

Comment: I've updated the regex in my answer based on your new inputs/outputs

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally, I want a pattern to eliminate from the end of the line to the
>   first match of "LIMIT".

Search for

```
/LIMIT((?!LIMIT).)*$/
```

and replace with nothing.